# vertical pipe symbol not being detected in NSURL

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I'm trying to place a search in google dictionary but the url contains a vertical pipe/bar |
My code just fails to load the site

```
 //http://www.google.com/dictionary?aq=f&langpair=en|en&q=test+test+test&hl=en


if ([mySearchEngineName isEqualToString:@"Google Dictionary"]){
        NSLog(@"Currently searching %@ using %@", mySearchString, mySearchEngineName); 

        NSString *mutateSearchString = [mySearchString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
        NSString *searchURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/dictionary?aq=f&langpair=en|en&q=%@&hl=en", mutateSearchString];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:searchURL];
        [webBrowser loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    }
```

using %7C did not work either..

```
NSString *searchURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/dictionary?aq=f&langpair=en%7Cen&q=%@&hl=en", mutateSearchString];
```

Comment: Can you let us know what error you got or in what way its failing to load. Also can you copy&paste a NSLog output of the full URL String for both the | and the %7C version of the string?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Consider encoding your URL using something like:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[searchURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

rather than manually doing it yourself. Perhaps there is some characters in your mySearchString NSString that also needs encoding. Run this encoding after you have **stringWithFormat**'d the full URL together.

Comment: NSURL *url =  [NSURL URLWithString:[searchURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];