# Unable to send multiple types "|" through to Google Places API via iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

Somehow, I am unable to send the following string over to Google Places API via iOS.

```
NSString string= @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%f,%f&radius=1000&sensor=true&types=restaurant|cemetery&key=<mykey>";
```

If without the pipe "|", it works though.

```
NSString string= @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%f,%f&radius=1000&sensor=true&types=restaurant&key=<mykey>"
```

Any idea why?

Through browser, both works.
Don't really know how to send the "|" through.

Comment: are you encoding the url? if not take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167331/vertical-pipe-symbol-not-being-detected-in-nsurl/6167660#6167660

Comment: Hahaha, mighty thanks! Do you want to repost this? So I can accept your answer?

Comment: nothing to thank, but not going to repost cause duplicate.