# How to use multiple types "|" for searching places with Google Place API in JAVA

Tags: java, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm unable to specify multiple types when searching places with the Google Place API  (from [table 1](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types?hl=fr&csw=1#table1) supported types). In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests), it is said that : "Types should be separated with a pipe symbol (type1|type2|etc)". When I specify one type like this:

```
Places.nearbySearch(new params().location(lat,long).query(req).keyword(key).types("restaurant"));
```

It works. But when I tried to add another type : `.types("restaurant|museum")` I had the exception "Illegal character in query at index...".
I checked other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167331/vertical-pipe-symbol-not-being-detected-in-nsurl/6167660#6167660) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566630/unable-to-send-multiple-types-through-to-google-places-api-via-ios), but solutions are not given in JAVA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets) library to access the Google Places API in Java.  The pipe symbol is not valid in the `types` method parameters.  To send a request with multiple types, specify each of them as individual parameters.  For example, `types("restaurant", "museum")`.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Yes I'm using Sprockets. Thanks !